# Protocol delegates of Objective C equivalent in xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I would like to use delegation design pattern to assign some tasks to child object and once its done it has to let me know so that I can act accordingly.

But in Objective c it can be done easily using Protocols.

I know Protocol equivalent is interface in C# but I couldn't find any examples on how to proceed delegation in c# I know we have to declare child object as weak or else cyclic reference will occur.

AFAIK delegation is not possible in c# if there are any other alternatives to achieve this thing

Explaining with a code snippet would be a good idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: Mixing C# and Obj-C terms here, ObjC in italic (I hope... ;-)

We create an interface that defines the *protocol* method(s) that an user would implement to extend the functionality of another class that accepts this *protocol* as a *delegate*:

#### The *Protocol*:

```
public interface IWorkerDelegate
{
    void PreformAdditionalWork();
}
```

#### The Class that accepts the *Protocol*:

Stored as the weak reference in this example, so hold a strong reference to the delegates that you assign...

```
public class Worker
{
    WeakReference<IWorkerDelegate> _workerDelegate;

    public IWorkerDelegate WorkerDelegate
    {
        get
        {
            IWorkerDelegate workerDelegate;
            return _workerDelegate.TryGetTarget(out workerDelegate) ? workerDelegate : null;
        }
        set
        {
            _workerDelegate = new WeakReference<IWorkerDelegate>(value);
        }
    }

    public async Task DoAlotOfWork()
    {
        // Do some work and continue with a delegate if assigned....
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker.DoAlotOfWork");
        })
        .ContinueWith((Task task) =>
        {
            if (_workerDelegate != null)
                WorkerDelegate?.PreformAdditionalWork();
        });
    }
}
```

#### An Implementation of that *Protocol*:

```
public class AdditionalWorkerDelegate : IWorkerDelegate
{
    public void PreformAdditionalWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IWorkerDelegate.PreformAdditionalWork");
    }
}
```

#### *Delegate* Usage Pattern:

```
var worker = new Worker();
await worker.DoAlotOfWork();
worker.WorkerDelegate = new AdditionalWorkerDelegate();
await worker.DoAlotOfWork();
```

#### Output:

```
Worker.DoAlotOfWork
Worker.DoAlotOfWork
IWorkerDelegate.PreformAdditionalWork
```

Comment: Great ! Thank you :)